# Gautschi's Motivation for polynomial interpolation error

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, interpolation, motivation, lagrange-interpolation

In the text Gautschi. Numerical analysis: an introduction, Birkhäuser, Boston, 1997; 2nd edition, 2012, Gautshi gives the following motivation for error in polynomial interpolation:

"It is not difficult to guess how the formula for the error should look: since the error is zero at each $x_i$, $i=0,1,...,n$, we ought to see a factor of the form $(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\cdots (x-x_n)$."

This part makes sense. He goes on to say

"On the other hand, by the projection property 3"[he is referring to the fact that if $P_n$ is the linear operator taking a continuous function to its $n$th degree interpolant, then $P_nf=f$ if $f$ is itself an $n$th degree polynomial] " the error is also zero (even identically so) if $f\in \mathbb{P}_n$, which suggests another factor-the $(n+1)$st derivative of $f$."

I begin to feel shaky here. I think what he is saying is that we know that the error is exactly $f^{(n+1)}$ evaluated at some point since the polynomial vanishes. I am uncertain though. He then says

"But evaluated where? Certainly not at $x$ since $f$ would then have to satisfy a differential equation. So let us say that $f^{(n+1)}$ is evaluated at some point $\xi=\xi(x)$, which is unknown but must be expected to depend on $x$. Now if we test the formula conjectured on simplest nontrivial polynomial $f(x)=x^{n+1}$, we discover a factor of $1/(n+1)!$ is missing. So our final guess is 
 $f(x)-p_n(f;x)=\dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi(x))}{(n+1)!}\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i), x\in [a,b]$.
"

At this point my questions are: What differential equation would $f$ have to satisfy? Why is it obvious that $\xi$ would depend on $x$? And How is he testing his guess with $f(x)=x^{n+1}$?

Comment: There are some leaps here. You know the error is zero at the nodes. You know the error is zero everywhere if f is a polynomial of degree at most n. This leads to the first two leaps. Now if $f^{(n+1)}(x)$ appeared in the error then the equation for the error relation would be a differential equation of order $n+1$ that f would satisfy which is generally not satisfied even by smooth functions. The last example is checking an example where the error can be computed exactly and then leaping to the general inclusion of the factor of $(n+1)!$.

Comment: Personally I would say a proof gives more insight than this handwaving explanation, and is not really that long.

Comment: I am familiar with the proof and it is definitely a nice one. From what you have said it seems like this motivation isn't really worth trying to understand.

Comment: Not to mention that there are [related problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3521630/316404) where the interpolation error doesn't even have the given form. It could perhaps be characterized as a mnemonic useful in routine instances, and while it's good to have such a mnemonic so we don't have to carry all that detail around in our heads, it's not a tool that can address the more challenging problems.

Comment: @Ian The only proof that I am aware of is the one which asks you to consider the function $$F(t) =f(t) - p(t) + \dfrac {f(x)-p(x)}{(x-x_0) \cdots (x-x_n)}(t-x_0) \cdots (t-x_n),$$ note that it has $n+2$ zeroes, so its derivative has $n+1$ zeroes, etc. Is this the proof you are thinking of?  I am really curious because this proof gives me pretty much zero insight. Would you mind explaining how it is insightful?

Comment: @Ovi It is generally in the same spirit, but still take a look at https://www.math.ubc.ca/~peirce/M406_Lecture_2_Error_in_Polynomial_Interpolation_Equally_spaced_Points.pdf The idea here is to write down the polynomial that *would* interpolate $f$ at $x_0,\dots,x_{n+1}$ using Newton interpolation and then bound the additional term using a Rolle-type argument.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for the insight and the link! I only learned Numerical Analysis from my professor and from the Gautschi book, I see that I need to broaden my horizons.